# How to get json response in Java in case of 4XX and 5XX error

Tags: java, retrofit2, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I was trying out **RestTemplate** and **Retrofit2**. Both the libraries throw exception in case api returns 4XX/5XX. **The api when hit from postman gives a JSON response body, along with 4XX/5XX**.
How can I retrieve this JSON response using RestTemplate or Retrofit2.

Thanks.

Comment: As answered, you can use the globalExceptionHandler to transform the response as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Use the `HttpClientErrorException`, `HttpStatusCodeException`  after try block as below.

```
    try{
        restTemplate.exchange("url", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
    }
    catch (HttpClientErrorException errorException){
        logger.info("Status code :: {}, Exception message :: {} , response body ::{}" , e.getStatusCode()
                e.getMessage(), e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
    catch (HttpStatusCodeException e){
        logger.info("Status code :: {}, Exception message :: {} , response body ::{}" , e.getStatusCode()
                e.getMessage(), e.getResponseBodyAsString());

    }
```

Comment: I tried this, e.getResponseBodyAsString() returns "HTTP 401"

Comment: What you got in the postman. 401 is unauthorized so in your code what you return for  unauthorized access.

Comment: I modified the code. can you try as above.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to create RestTemplateError handler and register that class while creating bean for RestTemplate.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate getBasicRestTemplate() {
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
     restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler());
     return restTemplate;
}
```

where your handler class has to implements **ResponseErrorHandler**. You can read the json response that is stored in the **body**.

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
        return httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == CLIENT_ERROR
                || httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == SERVER_ERROR;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == SERVER_ERROR) {
            LOGGER.error("Handling server error response statusCode:{} ", httpResponse.getStatusCode());
        } else if (httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == CLIENT_ERROR) {
            LOGGER.error("Handling Client error response statusCode:{} ", httpResponse.getStatusCode());
            String body;
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getBody(),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            body = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            throw new CustomException(httpResponse.getStatusCode().toString(), httpResponse, body);
        }
    }
}
```